# How to build up the creation/anihilation operators in Numerical Renormalization group?

Tags: operators, renormalization, computational-physics, hamiltonian, tight-binding

Let's define a simple 1D linear tight-binding model (no matter that NRG is trivial here or even fails, this is just an simple example to illustrate my point)
$$H = \sum t_j \hat{c}^\dagger_{j}\hat{c}_{j+1}+ h.c$$

Suppose we use a renormalization technique: Let's assumme we can construct and diagonalize the hamiltonian $H_N$ that models $N$ sites, the resulting matrix has dimension $D$. We then define a projection operator formed by $m$ of the eigenstates, $P$, a matrix with $m$ columns (and $N$ rows) formed by the first $m$ eigenvectors (well, in NRG at least. In DMRG they would come from the eigenstates of the reduced Density from the diagonalization of a superblock, etc, but this is not very important for what I want to ask). We renormalize the hamiltonian: $H_N \rightarrow P'H_NP$ and also any other relevant operators. The hamiltonian  for $N$ sites is now approximated as the renormalized operator $\tilde{H}_N= P'H_NP$ that has dimensions $m \times m,$ not $D \times D$.

In the next step, we want to build up the hamiltonian matrx for $N+1$ sites. . The dimension of the new big matrix we will diagonalize will be $4m.$ To construct it, however, is key to write down the matrix form of the creation/anihilation operators for the (N+1)-th site. But, how to do this? In a chain of N sites (forget any renormalization for a second), it's easy to write down the matrix of the operator for each of the sites through tensor products of identity matrices, sympletic matrices and the creation/anihilation operators for just one site. But, in this case, after all the renormalizations trough the different iteration steps have been done, **how can I write down this matrix?** Clearly it is not just the tensor product
$$\text{I}_{m} \otimes c,$$
with $\text{I}_m$ the identity matrix of dimension $m$ and $c$ the matrix for the creation (or anihilation) operator on a single site, since this overall matrix does not anticommute with the creation/anihilation operators on other sites.

Comment: Have you ever read the review by Bulla ( https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.80.395 )? I think that is a good reference.